# Import a module inside a module using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a requirement like I need to create a module to perform some of my own tasks but it needs volley library, So i am trying to import volley library which is cloned from `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley`
in to my module, But I cant find import module in context of the module. I am using Android studio 1.5, How could i import volley into my module not in main project?

Comment: Either you can place `Volley` binary file inside `libs` directory of your module or proceed it like #Kedi said.

Answer (score 0):

Add volley library in your module > build.gradle > dependencies.

Ex:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' //new version
}
```

and module in your application's build.gradle file.

Comment: So cant use official volley?

Comment: Other option is also there, If you added the volley library as a module then add this line to your module :  module > build.gradle > dependencies > compile project(':modules:module-volley') //whatever you gave module name

Answer (score 0):

You can, Suppose your gradle project and volley lib src project is in same location.

Edit your project setting.gradle to include volley project.

```
include ':android-volley'
project(':android-volley').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../android-volley')
```

Then add volley project dependency to your project build.gradle

```
compile project(':android-volley')
```

*** If you don't need source project of volley try maven dependency.

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```